# Come si dice "stem cell research" in Italiano?

Tags: phrase-request

Buongiorno,

Volevo sapere se qualcuno mi può aiutare a sapere come si dice "stem cell research" in Italiano.

Grazie, era da un po' che volevo usare questa parola, ma non so come si dice.

Comment: “Ricerca sulle cellule staminali”?

Comment: Grazie, @DaG... ma la stamina non è sinonimo di energia? Come si risolve questa ambiguità in Italiano? Grazie.

Comment: No. *Stamina* è una parola inglese, che non esiste in italiano. Sia la parola inglese *stamina* che la parola italiana “staminale” vengono alla lontana dal latino *stamen* (una parte del fiore), ma hanno preso strade diverse.

Comment: ricerca di cella tronco ?

Answer (score 7):

Il termine usato in italiano per tradurre *stem cell* è *cellula staminale* o più raramente *cellula stipite*, come puoi vedere in questo lemma del [vocabolario Treccani online](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/staminale2/).
Dunque *stem cell research* si dice *ricerca sulle cellule staminali*, oppure, usando l'aggettivo sostantivato, *ricerca sulle staminali*.
Il termine *stem* in inglese deriva come l'italiano *staminale* dal latino *stamen -mĭnis* «stame, filo».
Forse il tuo dubbio può nascere dal fatto che la parola inglese *stamina* somiglia molto a *staminale* ed ha un altro significato. In italiano si può tradurre con *energia, forza o resistenza*.